# What 60s movie has a girl with alien and human identities who leaves earth with a human man?

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I’m searching for the name of the movie from the sixties (if I remember correctly).

It is about the aliens from a spaceship that crashed on Earth. The movie ends in K-PAX style - the main hero from our planet leaves his body and is shown as dead person, and a girl with double identities (alien and human) leaves the human one. It all ends somewhere in grassland with body of the hero and a living girl without memories.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be [Starman](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088172/) (1984)? The overview seems to fit and it certainly ends with the hero in a field with no memory of how he got there...

Comment: Thank you very much for quick reaction but... Forgotten movie is definitely not Starman which I have and I know it quite well. "My" film was done much earlier.

Comment: Excellent. This is it. I watched the end of a movie at YT and that's exactly what I searched for. TYVM.

Answer (score 2):

The movie you're looking for is called Night Slaves,based on a novel of the same name by Jerry Sohl. It was a "made for tv", shown in 1970,  starring James Franciscus. Aliens crash and have hypnotized a town in helping them repair their ship. The hero is immune to their control and falls in love with one of them, who is possessing the body of one the town's women. The end scene is our hero dead in a field with the unpossessed woman who doesn't remember what happened. A more complete synopsis here: http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/night_slaves

Comment: Looks like this question was related to this one:https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/44848/movie-about-sleepwalking-people-repairing-an-alien-spaceship?rq=1