# Is the Stargate SG-1 episode "Nightwalkers" a retelling of an older story, and if so, which one?

Tags: story-identification, stargate, stargate-sg1, inspiration

When I was watching the *SG-1* episode "Nightwalkers", I had this strange sense of déjà vu - like I'd seen a similar story line (aliens recruit unwitting townsfolk to rebuild/repair their crashed/disabled spaceship) play out in some other TV show or movie produced years before.

Was it really an original *SG-1* story or was it, as I suspect, an *SG-1* version of what I would think is a stock sci-fi plot?

Comment: If you're asking specifically about where the inspiration for that Stargate episode came from, the [tag:inspiration] tag might be better than [tag:story-identification].

Comment: Sounds like something that should be in Twilight Zone / Outer Limits / X-Files.

Comment: Reminded me of Steven King's work, small town oddness. Possibly The Tommyknockers? According to a quick google search it was adapted to tv in 1993.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/44848/movie-about-sleepwalking-people-repairing-an-alien-spaceship) question concerns a story that sounds to me very similar to that *SG-1* episode - a movie called "Night Slaves" apparently has the same idea in 1970.

Comment: I just looked it up on IMDB (and even Wikipedia has an article on it). The Wikipedia article associates it with a few other movies (Duel, The Night Stalker, Killdozer) which were contemporary "movies of the week" and all of which I remember watching in their first run, so I'm sure this is the origin of my "deja vu".

Comment: The movie "Killdozer" was made from a novella by the same name, written by Theodore Sturgeon. It has been one of my favorite stories for decades.